# Item Resizing when using Locators

Tags: manipulate, locator

I am having some difficulty in resizing a Stream Plot when using locators: Whenever I try to resize the Stream Plot, one of the locators instead moves to the cursor.

```
Manipulate[{StreamPlot[{(
 q1 (x - p[[1]]))/((x - p[[1]])^2 + (y - p[[2]])^2)^(3/2) + (
 q2 (x - q[[1]]))/((x - q[[1]])^2 + (y - q[[2]])^2)^(3/2), (
 q1 (y - p[[2]]))/((x - p[[1]])^2 + (y - p[[2]])^2)^(3/2) + (
 q2 (y - q[[2]]))/((x - q[[1]])^2 + (y - q[[2]])^2)^(3/2)}, {x, 0,
 10}, {y, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 10}]},
 {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}, {{q, {1, 1}}, Locator}, {q1, -4, 4}, {q2, -4,4}]
```

How can I rectify this behaviour?

Comment: resize? why not add an manipulator about ImageSize

Comment: that's what locators do -- they go to the cursor. Just add ImageSize->500 (or whatever size you want) or control the size with a slider if you want it dynamic. I would also remove the brackets around the StreamPlot -- no need for them in the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
Manipulate[
   StreamPlot[{(q1 (x - p[[1]]))/((x - p[[1]])^2 + 
     (y - p[[2]])^2)^(3/2) + (q2 (x - q[[1]]))/((x - q[[1]])^2 + 
     (y - q[[2]])^2)^(3/2), (q1 (y - p[[2]]))/((x - p[[1]])^2 + 
     (y - p[[2]])^2)^(3/2) + (q2 (y - q[[2]]))/((x - q[[1]])^2 + 
     (y - q[[2]])^2)^(3/2)}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 10}, 
     ImageSize -> siz], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}, {{q, {1, 1}}, Locator}, 
          {q1, -4, 4}, {q2, -4, 4}, {siz, 100, 600}]
```